# How do I build on a query string?

Tags: php, query-string

What I have is that when someone clicks a link on my index it calls `index.php?action=signup` and that will display a signup form.

How do I then cause the signup form to maintain the `action=signup` portion of the query string so that when the user clicks "Submit" the new query string is `index.php?action=signup&email=user@email.com`?

What is the best way to set this up? Should I somehow split the actions into `GET` and the data into `POST`?

I am not sure if I am describing this correctly but I want to keep all my functions on the `index.php` so when I integrate `.htaccess` everything will be like `www.site.com/signup`, `www.site.com/login` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this on a form submission is to change the `<form>` action to the correct URL and the method to `GET`, like so:

`<form action="index.php?action=signup" method="GET">`

Then, hidden in your form, you put something like the following:

`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="signup" />`

Then your URL will contain the correct parameters when it is submitted.

However, if you need to modify this server side, then you can get all of your query parameters via `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Use [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to get an array of values, and use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) to recreate the query string:

Example:

```
$params = array();
parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $params);
$params['email'] = 'user@email.com';
echo http_build_query( $params); // Will output a new query string for your URLs
```

Comment: Instead of using $_SERVER, look at using $_GET or $_REQUEST. They are already in an array format.

Comment: @nickb what hafichuk probably meant was to copy the contents of `$_GET` (or use it directly) instead of parsing `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` using  `parse_str`.